# How to Change Controller Name URL in Grails?

Tags: grails, controller

I'm trying to change default convention of controller name in Grails. My Controller Class is named `LongNameInCamelCaseController`. Grails convention over configuration sets an url mapping for this controller like `longNameInCamelCase`. I want this controller name in url friendly `'long-name-in-camel-case'`.

Someone already do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's described in the docs here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#customizingUrlFormat

Add

```
grails.web.url.converter = 'hyphenated'
```

in `Config.groovy`